# Async method only works when MessageDialog is called

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await

I am very new to C# and still trying to understand how async methods work. My UWP app needs to retrieve a thumbnail JPG from a compressed folder when it is dropped onto the screen, display the thumbnail with a progress ring while the folder is uploading, and then remove the progress ring when upload is complete.

First this method is triggered when the user drops a file:

```
private async void OnFileDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
    {
        var items = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();
        if (items.Count > 0)
        {

                foreach (var appFile in items.OfType<StorageFile>())
                {

                    StorageFolder downloadFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

                    StorageFolder unzipFolder =
                await downloadFolder.CreateFolderAsync(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(appFile.Name),
                CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

                    await UnZipFileAsync(appFile, unzipFolder);

                }
        }
    }
```

Next:

```
public static IAsyncAction UnZipFileAsync(StorageFile zipFile, StorageFolder destinationFolder, Action<ZipArchiveEntry, StorageFolder> callback, Action<ZipArchiveEntry> completeCallback)
    {
        return UnZipFileHelper(zipFile, destinationFolder, thumbnailCallback, completeCallback).AsAsyncAction();
    }
```

Then this Task unzips the file, calling the thumbnailCallback method after the ZipArchive has been created:

```
 private static async Task UnZipFileHelper(StorageFile zipFile, StorageFolder destinationFolder, Action<ZipArchiveEntry, StorageFolder> thumbnailCallback, Action<ZipArchiveEntry> completeCallback)
    {
        if (zipFile == null || destinationFolder == null ||
            !Path.GetExtension(zipFile.Name).Equals(".zip", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            )
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid argument...");
        }

        Stream zipMemoryStream = await zipFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

        // Create zip archive to access compressed files in memory stream
        using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipMemoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
        {
            ZipArchiveEntry thumbnail = zipArchive.GetEntry("thumbnail.jpg");

            thumbnailCallback(thumbnail, destinationFolder);

            // Unzip compressed file iteratively.
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in zipArchive.Entries)
            {
                await UnzipZipArchiveEntryAsync(entry, entry.FullName, destinationFolder);

            }
        }
    }
```

This is the thumbnailCallback method which is *supposed* to display the thumbnail while the folder is being uploaded:

```
public async void thumbnailCallback(ZipArchiveEntry thumbnail, StorageFolder destinationFolder)
{
        // thumbnail only displays after this has been called and user clicks OK button to close dialog
        var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("displaying thumbnail");
        await messageDialog.ShowAsync();

        // code to display thumbnail

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.Width = 200;
        canvas.Height = 125;
        ProgressRing progressRing = new ProgressRing();
        progressRing.Name = thumbnail.FullName;
        progressRing.IsActive = true;
        progressRing.Height = 50;
        progressRing.Width = 50;
        Canvas.SetTop(progressRing, 35);
        Canvas.SetLeft(progressRing, 75);
        Canvas.SetZIndex(progressRing, 2);

        Image thumb = new Image();
        thumb.Name = thumbnail.FullName;
        thumb.Width = 200;
        thumb.Height = 125;
        thumb.Opacity = 0.2;

        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        Uri uri = new Uri(destinationFolder.Path + "\\" + thumbnail.FullName);
        bitmapImage.UriSource = uri;
        thumb.Source = bitmapImage;

        canvas.Children.Add(thumb);
        canvas.Children.Add(progressRing);




    }
```

Right now the thumbnail will only display if MessageDialog.ShowAsync() is called first, and it does not appear until the OK button has been clicked on the dialog box.

Comment: If the code to display the thumbnail is after the `await` then the behavior your seeing is expected. Move the code to display the thumbnail before the call to `ShowAsync`.

Comment: I understand that, the issue is I don't want that MessageDialog to appear at all, but if I remove it the rest of the code does not work.

Comment: Does the program end if you remove the Message Dialog?

Comment: @jdweng no, it continues to upload the folder, it just does not display the thumbnail while uploading.

Comment: Right now your original code doesn't compile so it's hard to say, the number of parameters used for `UnZipFileHelper` are mismatched. You may be able to get away with simply removing `async` and `ShowDialogAsync` entirely from the `thumbnailCallback`. If that doesn't work we'd need to see the code used to display the thumbnail.

Comment: @JSteward the mismatched parameters were just a mistake on here, I updated my answer to reflect the actual code. I also added the code for displaying the thumbnail. Removing `async` and `ShowDialogAsync` did not work

Comment: `var x = await Task.Run(SomeMethod)`  You can use that and remove the `async` designation from all sub calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thumbnailCallback` is called without `await`. That's the reason thumnail are not not displayed (if you are lucky you may get thumbnail randomly :)). When you put MessageDialog then thread is enough time to execute after user interaction.

**How to Fix**

Call it like as below:

```
await thumbnailCallback(thumbnail, destinationFolder);
```

**Suggestion :**

Change the signature as

```
public async Task thumbnailCallback(ZipArchiveEntry thumbnail, StorageFolder destinationFolder)
```

Normally, you would want to return a `Task`. The main exception should be when you need to have a void return type (for events).

`async` methods that return void are special in another aspect: they represent top-level `async` operations, and have additional rules that come into play when your task returns an `exception`.

Comment: I am getting the following error: Task MainPage.thumbnailCallback(ZipArchiveEntry, StorageFolder)' has the wrong return type

Comment: I added the return statement, and am now getting this error: Since 'MainPage.thumbnailCallback(ZipArchiveEntry, StorageFolder)' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task<T>'?

Comment: Do you have any awaitable Task inside the method `thumbnailCallback`?

Comment: And when I changed it to 'Task<T>', I got this: 'Task<T>' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: No there aren't

Comment: You should change it to Task<bool>. T is type if you are accepting then you should define it. Change the return statement as `return true` Or `return await Task.FromResult(true)`;

Comment: I am still getting an error: 'Task<bool> MainPage.thumbnailCallback(ZipArchiveEntry, StorageFolder)' has the wrong return type

Comment: `thumbnailCallback` is a delegate passed as an `Action<ZipArchiveEntry, StorageFolder>`

Comment: @JSteward so will I have to implement it a different way?

Comment: @LauraM - As mentioned by JSteward, the Signature of thumbnailcallback is `Action<ZipArchiveEntry, StorageFolder>` which has changed after above recommendation, so you changed it to `Func<ZipArchiveEntry, StorageFolder,Task<bool>>` in function `UnZipFileHelper` if you are going to return bool from method or `Func<ZipArchiveEntry, StorageFolder, Task>` if  signature is going to be `public async Task thumbnailCallback(.....`